# Let the user create Azure Active Directory App registrations for our app?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We just had a customer, Acme, request that they be able to create their own app registration to represent our SaaS app.  So far we've managed the app registration ourselves and had one definition that's then shared with all customers.

They requested this for a couple for reasons:

1. They want to give the app another name, to match their internal naming conventions.
2. They want to change the URL of the app from app.product.com to acme.product.com so they can click on the app in the App gallery and be taken to directly to their instance, instead of manually browsing to acme.product.com.

These are reasonable requests, and I get it, but if every customer has their own app registration then our support overhead goes way up, because we have to hold their hand as they set it up and then make sure it's updated whenever we have to make changes (quite rarely, mind you).

Is this a common pattern and we just have to deal with it, or is this all better solved in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sync the configurations between your Azure AD app and the customer's, the best way is using [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing).

Unfortunately customer cannot modify the app name and reply url in this case.

[Publish your app to the Azure AD app gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing) and customer can [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal) it from their tenant would allow them to modify the name and reply url.